# How to add dynamic class to Html.Raw?

Tags: c#, razor

Is there are way to dynamically create html in razor and dynamically add a class? This is what I have so far, but class comes back empty in browser.

```
var tdClass = (i % 2 == 0) ? "" : "alternate_row";

@Html.Raw("<tr class='"+tdClass+"'>")
```

Comment: Is that a typo with the extra single quote in there?

Comment: If you want to style alternate rows you could use css itself. `tr:nth-child(odd)`, `tr:nth-child(even)` http://caniuse.com/#search=nth-child

Comment: Yes, updated but that still does not fix it.

Comment: Yeah, @PSL I may just do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing the closing single quote "'" after the class name:

```
@Html.Raw("<tr class='"+tdClass+"'>")
```